# Differences between 2 branches after merge: GIT

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-diff

I am currently working on a second branch called `NC12-changePassword`.

There have been changes made to `master` branch which handle decrypting of a string. I required these new changes to be able to implement a new feature on my branch so I merged the changes.

I did a git pull and there were no conflicts. When I run `git log` it shows the merge commit. Also when I run `git merge master` it tells me everything is up to date.

However my code is not working and when I run git `diff NC12-changePassword master` it lists what's in `master` that isn't in `NC12-changePassword`. This doesn't make sense to me because I have merged the changes and therefore the everything that is in master should be in `NC12-changePassword`.

My understanding is that my branch should function like `master` and the code should work fine. Or am I missing something :-\ .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> and therefore the everything that is in master should be in NC12-changePassword

That's not what "merge" means, and therefore not what `git merge` does.

Let's take a very simple example for illustration.  Suppose you made a branch off master and, as part or even all of that branch, you deleted a block of code and committed the result.

Then, after you've done that, suppose Fred modifies `master` to add a second block of code—perhaps in a different file entirely—that only does something useful if the first block of code exists.  He commits that to `master`.

Later, you obtain Fred's work in `master` and use `git merge` to bring his-changes-to-master into your branch.  Git will *not* put back the code you deleted: it assumes you knew what you were doing then.  All it will do is discover that Fred added a *new* block of code, and it will add that same block to your branch, where it does nothing because it depends on the block you deleted.

If you now compare your branch to Fred's `master`, you will still have a deleted block of code: the block you deleted.  You won't have *everything* that's in that `master`.  (Your own `master` will probably not have Fred's changes either, because in the above, we've never mentioned you getting on to *your* `master` and bringing in his changes from his `master`.)

In complicated situations, you must use your own knowledge (which will always exceed git's) to fix up merges that are semantically incorrect.  Git will, at most, notice syntactic collisions, things like: "hey, you deleted this block of code, but Fred made a change to that same block, so since I, git, know nothing of semantics, you will have to resolve this conflict".  But this happens only if you are lucky enough to have a syntactic conflict.  If Fred's changes "fit in" despite your changes, but do nothing because of your changes, git won't even notice that.